# Agrupar datos con Group by

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero agrupar los datos de un menu pero no logro hacerlo.

db user

```
id | nombre
-----------
1  | pedro
```

db menu

```
idm    | userid | mfecha
------------------------
1      | 1      | 2020-11-08
```

db listamenu

```
idlista | menuid | lcate      | lproducto           | lvalor
--------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 1      | pizzas     | Muza + Ceveza       | 800
2       | 1      | pizzas     | Napolitana + Ceveza | 860
3       | 1      | pizzas     | Fugazzeta + Ceveza  | 900
4       | 1      | bebidas    | Gaseosas o Jugos    | 80
5       | 1      | cafeteria  | Cafe + tostado      | 280
6       | 1      | cafeteria  | Cafe + Torta        | 250
```

codigo php

```
class ListaMenu extends Database {
  public function getMenu($userid){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM listamenu INNER JOIN menu ON menu.idm = listamenu.menuid WHERE userid = ? GROUP BY lcate";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($userid));

    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $resultado;
  }
}

$dato = new ListaMenu();
$userid = 1; //id usuairo autorizado

$lista = $dato->getMenu($userid);
?>
Menu
<?php
foreach($lista as $row){
?>

<?=$row['lcate'];?><br>
$<?=$row['lproducto'];?> $<?=$row['lvalor'];?><br>

<?php
}
?>
```

El resultado que obtengo

```
Pizzas
Muza + Ceveza    $800

Bebidas
Gaseosas o Jugos $80

Cafeteria
Cafe + tostado   $280
```

El resultado deberia ser

```
Pizzas
Muza + Ceveza       $800
Napolitana + Ceveza $860
Fugazzeta + Ceveza  $900

Bebidas
Gaseosas o Jugos    $80

Cafeteria
Cafe + tostado $280
Cafe + Torta   $250
```

Comment: En la instrucción SQL pusiste `userid` y en la descripción de la tabla indicas que la columna se llama `iduser`. En una de las dos está mal. Si no funciona, dinos qué no funciona, si arroja error, qué error, si arroja datos, qué datos.

Comment: Me equivoque e incorpore el resultado que obtengo.

Comment: estas agrupando justamente por ese campo... porque aplicas el group by? para lograr que cosa?

Comment: Lo que quiero lograr es que me agrupe el menu. La categoria pizzas y sus varierdades y asi con el resto de categorias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo entender lo que necesitas y, como te comenta @gbianchi, no lo conseguirás con un `GROUP BY`. Así que, como primer paso, elimina `GROUP BY lcate` de tu consulta y, en vez de tu `foreach()`, te propongo el siguiente:

```
$lcate=null;
foreach($lista as $r){
    if($lcate!=$r['lcate']){
        $lcate=$r['lcate'];
        echo '<br/>'.$r['lcate'].'<br/>';
    } 
    echo $r['lproducto'].' '.$r['lvalor'].'<br/>';
}
```

Ya me comentas si es lo que buscabas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Aporto el dataset para las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE listamenu(
  id_lista int,
  menuid int,
  lcate varchar(15),
  lproducto varchar(31),
  lvalor float
  );

INSERT INTO listamenu (id_lista, menuid, lcate, lproducto, lvalor) VALUES
('1','1','pizzas','Muza + Ceveza','800'),
('2','1','pizzas','Napolitana + Ceveza','860'),
('3','1','pizzas','Fugazzeta + Ceveza','900'),
('4','1','bebidas','Gaseosas o Jugos','80'),
('5','1','cafeteria','Cafe + tostado','280'),
('6','1','cafeteria','Cafe + Torta','250');
```

Así como el PHP mínimo para verificar el resultado:

```
<?php

$conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','so');
$lista=$conn->query("
    SELECT * FROM listamenu
      ORDER BY lcate;
")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$lcate=null;
foreach($lista as $r){
    if($lcate!=$r['lcate']){
        $lcate=$r['lcate'];
        echo '<br/>'.$r['lcate'].'<br/>';
    } 
    echo $r['lproducto'].' '.$r['lvalor'].'<br/>';
}
```

El resultado es:

```
bebidas
Gaseosas o Jugos 80

cafeteria
Cafe + tostado 280
Cafe + Torta 250

pizzas
Muza + Ceveza 800
Napolitana + Ceveza 860
Fugazzeta + Ceveza 900
```

Comment: Gracias David, habia intentado hacer algo similar, pero no me agrupa las categorias. El resultado es `pizzas Grande de muza + Cerveza $750
pizzas Jamon y morrones + Cerveza $800
bebidas Gaseosas o Jugos $80
cafeteria Cafe + Tostado $250` y deberia ser `pizzas todo el menu, bebias y todo el menu`. Es por eso que intente agrupar desde mysql pero tampoco tuve buenos resultados

Comment: ¿Lo has probado tal cual te lo he pasado? Debería funcionar...

Comment: Si si, lo probe, juro que probe y me sale asi: `pizzas
Grande de muza + Cerveza 750
pizzas
Jamon y morrones + Cerveza 800
bebidas
Gaseosas o Jugos 80
cafeteria
Cafe + Tostado 250`

Comment: Perdona, me equivoqué de campo al agrupar en el `foreach()`. Ya está arreglado :)

Comment: Gracias David. Habia borrado el `group by` y no me daba resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Después de realizar intentos agotadores, finalmente tengo la respuesta idéntica a como la querías en puro SQL.

Utilicé un *STORED PROCEDURE* con parámetros para crear una tabla auxiliar (`lcategroup`), y una tabla resultado (`result`).

La tabla resultado será poblarla con los `SELECT` y `UNION` con el formato deseado.

Luego imprimir el resultado, y finalmente borrar las tablas creadas.

Espero que el código y los comentarios lo expliquen por si mismos.

Primero creamos el STORED PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_table(IN _userid INT)
BEGIN

    -- [INICIO] Variables
    DECLARE lcatenum INT;
    DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 1;
    -- [FIN] Variables

    -- [INICIO] Tabla resultado
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result (
        col1 varchar(100),
        col2 varchar(100)
    );
    -- [FIN] Tabla resultado

    -- [INICIO] Tabla de ayuda de catagorias
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lcate_group (
        idlcate INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        lcatename varchar(100)
    );
    INSERT INTO lcate_group
        SELECT 
            NULL, lcate
        FROM listamenu
        GROUP BY lcate;
    -- [FIN] Tabla de ayuda de catagorias

    -- [INICIO] Asignamos limite
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lcate_group INTO lcatenum;
    -- [FIN] Asignamos limite

    -- [INICIO] Llenado de tabla resultado
    WHILE contador <= lcatenum DO

        INSERT INTO result (col1, col2)
            SELECT
                CONCAT(
                    UPPER(LEFT(lcatename,1)),
                    SUBSTRING(lcatename,2)
                    ),
                ''
            FROM lcate_group
            WHERE idlcate = contador
            UNION
            SELECT
                lproducto,
                concat('$', lvalor)
            FROM listamenu
                JOIN menu
                    ON menu.idm = listamenu.menuid
            WHERE
                userid = _userid
                AND lcate = ( SELECT lcatename
                              FROM lcate_group
                              WHERE idlcate = contador);

        SELECT contador;

        SET contador = contador + 1;
    END WHILE;
    -- [FIN] Llenado de tabla resultado
    
    -- [INICIO] Mostrar resultado
    SELECT * FROM result;
    -- [FIN] Mostrar resultado

    -- [INICIO] Limpiar tablas
    DROP TABLE lcate_group;
    DROP TABLE result;
    -- [FIN] Limpiar tablas
END;
```

Después lo llamamos con `CALL`, suponiendo que el userid es 1:

```
CALL create_table(1)

col1                 col2
Pizzas               ""
Muza + Ceveza        $800
Napolitana + Ceveza  $860
Fugazzeta + Ceveza   $900
Bebidas              ""
Gaseosas o Jugos     $80
Cafeteria            ""
Cafe + tostado       $280
Cafe + Torta         $250
```

Si ya no quieres el STORED PROCEDURE, lo puedes borrar con `DROP PROCEDURE create_table`. Luego lo puedes modificar si gustas.

Otra respuesta es tan sólo usar un `JOIN`, quitar el `group` (que en realidad parece no necesitarse) quedando la consulta así (suponiendo que el `userid` es 1):

```
SELECT
  listamenu.lcate,
  lproducto,
  concat('$', lvalor)
FROM listamenu
JOIN menu
    ON menu.idm = listamenu.menuid
WHERE
  userid = 1;
```

Y resultando en esto:

```
lcate      lproducto            "concat('$',lvalor)"
pizzas     Muza + Ceveza        $800
pizzas     Napolitana + Ceveza  $860
pizzas     Fugazzeta + Ceveza   $900
bebidas    Gaseosas o Jugos     $80
cafeteria  Cafe + tostado       $280
cafeteria  Cafe + Torta         $250
```